# Mercurial "hg Clone" gives "abort: 00changelog.i@dfd87cee87f2: unknown parent!"

Tags: firefox, mercurial, mozilla

i am trying to start looking into Mozilla firefox source code for contributing, and the instructions at

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Simple_Firefox_build

tell me to execute this command

> Get the latest source code from Mozilla's Mercurial code repository.
>   This may take a while, it's a lot of code!
>
> `hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central`

so i downloaded hg, which was tortoiseHG for windows, and executed this command, but i am constantly getting this error :

```
D:\mozilla-src>hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
destination directory: mozilla-central
requesting all changes
adding changesets
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: 00changelog.i@dfd87cee87f2: unknown parent!
```

please help me

Comment: For reference: the "all-in-one" download contains the usual Mercurial along with TortoiseHg which is an additional (but not required) application making working with hg simpler for those disliking the command line. Unfortunately, I cannot help with the actual problem - I cloned Mozilla's repository a number of times and have never seen this error.

Comment: @WladimirPalant well yes i noted that, and i have tried "Cloning" mozilla from both GUI and CLI but i get same error in both. Also, if it helps, i am doing this in an Empty folder.

Comment: No, this error has nothing to do with folders - it's about a corrupted repository. Only that I'm pretty certain that mozilla-central is fine (it is under heavy use). Maybe the response from the Mozilla server got corrupted somehow.

Comment: i asked on IRC, found that "unfortunately, today is kind of a bad day - server issues." so issue resolved.

Comment: Strange, http://status.mozilla.com/ isn't listing any issues with hg.mozilla.org.

Comment: @Wladimir: yes, well because it has been fixed, you are checking it after about 9 hours :)

Comment: You should be looking at "Performance and Availability History" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pheonix mentioned, this is a server-side known issue that we hope to have wrapped up today.

@WladimirPalant status.mozilla.com is an automated tool watching for various returns, mostly HTTP codes and such. In this case it doesn't know about hg errors.

also, this only happens with newer hg on the client side (as our recent hg upgrade provides new capabilities that aren't quite working through the stack)